# Python "logging" module get access to log message for parsing

Tags: python, python-2.7, elasticsearch

I want a logging module that parses the log message and sends it to a database for later analysis (I'm using the Elasticsearch database). My current implementation uses the `logging` module and has all the standard debug levels. To do this, I need access to the log message. Is there a method in Python's `logging` module that would get me access to the message?

I feel like this boils down to writing a log handler that fits within Python's `logging` module. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like the "getMessage()" method might be what I want (https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.LogRecord).

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2

```
class StoredLogger(logging.Logger):

    def makeRecord(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        return logging.LogRecord(*args, **kwargs)

logging.setLoggerClass(StoredLogger)
```

Within `makeRecord`, you could add a call to a function like `store_message`, whose behavior you define.

```
def store_message(*args, **kwargs):
    """Write a message to the database"""
    ...
```

### Python 3.2+

> [Changed in version 3.2: The creation of a LogRecord has been made more configurable by providing a factory which is used to create the record. The factory can be set using getLogRecordFactory() and setLogRecordFactory() (see this for the factory’s signature).](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.LogRecord)

```py
old_factory = logging.getLogRecordFactory()

def new_factory(*args, **kwargs):
    record = old_factory(*args, **kwargs)
    record.custom_attribute = 0xDECAFBAD
    return record

logging.setLogRecordFactory(new_factory)
```

You would add your call to `store_message` into your `record_factory`.

```
def record_factory(*args, **kwargs):
    store_message(*args, **kwargs)

    global old_factory
    return old_factory(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then, when you use something like `logging.info('foo')`, it will pass through `store_message`, then resume its normal behavior by writing to its out-stream. You may want to consider renaming `record_factory` to something more descriptive like `stored_record_factory`.

Comment: I suppose I should have said that I am using python 2.7.5. According to https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html: "Changed in version 3.2: The creation of a LogRecord has been made more configurable by providing a factory which is used to create the record." Is what I want to do possible under python 2.7.5? I'm still working through your code. Thanks!

Comment: @CheesePita: In Python 2, you'll need to override `Logger.makeRecord` in a `Logger` subclass. I'll add an example of that to my answer when I get a chance.

Comment: @CheesePita: I've added distinct sections for Python 2/3 to my answer.